# Get the region between 2 overlapping ellipses

Tags: c#, winforms

This may be more of a math question, but lets say I have 2 overlapping ellipses:

[image]

How do I find the region between the 2 ellipses (the area between the inner and outer ellipse), given that I have only the 2 equations of the ellipses. I am trying to do this in Winforms but I don't think that the framework has any such functions.

Comment: This is a math question. Having the equations of the two ellipses, you have to find a solution to the problem of describing the region between them, if there exist at all any such a region. I say so, because the drawn ellipses you is one instance of your problem. There could be other configurations between two ellipses. That being said, I would first trying to describe my problem in the language of mathematics. Then solve it there and I would resort at the last step  in programming.

Comment: This is really no problem in winforms. And you got it all in your question: The key is `Region` which you create from two `GraphicsPaths` with one `Ellipse`in each. Then you `Exclude` the two `Regions. (`Regions` have all sorty of set operations.) Done.- The only question would be: What do you want to do with the result?  `Region` is a graphics type of object, not a mathematical one!

Comment: Have you resolved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the region to draw it or in it, this is how to do it:

```
private void Form2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(11, 11, 222, 111);
    Rectangle R2 = new Rectangle(44, 44, 111, 55);

    GraphicsPath GP1 = new GraphicsPath();
    GraphicsPath GP2 = new GraphicsPath();

    GP1.AddEllipse(R1);
    GP2.AddEllipse(R2);

    Region Re1 = new Region(GP1);
    Region Re2 = new Region(GP2);

    Re1.Exclude(Re2);           // subtract the inner region

    e.Graphics.Clip = Re1;      // restrict the Graphics to the region
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.DarkOrange);
    e.Graphics.ResetClip();    // maybe reset the clip

}
```

Here is the result:

[image]